# Firebase Hosting con Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex

tengo un problema con Firebase Hosting al subir mi projecto Vue.js que se conecta con firebase

La arquitectura de los archivos es el siguiente.

[image: La arquitectura de los archivos es el siguiente.]

y el archivo `firebase.json` es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o en codigo

```
{
 "hosting": {
  "public": "src",
  "ignore": [
     "firebase.json",
     "**/.*",
     "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Screenshot del error de firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos, gracias de antemano.

Comment: y cual es el error?

Comment: Hola el error es que cuando hago el deploy me sale que no encuentra el archivl index.html

Comment: añade entonces esa información a tu pregunta, de otro modo quien lo lea te estará solicitando la misma aclaración

Comment: Lo modificare con

Comment: @AlfredoPaz ya esta gracias, por pedirme editarlo, me olvide de poner esa parte :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te esta diciendo que no encuentra el archivo `index.html` en la carpeta que designaste, en este caso `"public": "src"`.

Prueba primero cambiando la carpeta public en `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Luego ejecuta `npm run build` para crear la carpeta `dist` donde se crean los archivos listos para producción que vas a subir, y finalmente ejecutas `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono a la perfeccion :D.